# replace an item from a list with the corresponding member from another list

Tags: c#, regex

Let's say I have a shorthand notation for writing symbols that are hard to type.  Writing `a'`, for example, would represent `á`.  I could make a whole sequence of regular expressions to transform these, such as:

```
 a' --> á
 e' --> é
 i' --> í
 o' --> ó
 u' --> ú
```

but what I'd rather have is a single regex that handles a range of cases:

```
 [aeiou]' --> [áéíóú]
```

In other words, when the regex parser finds a match using the nth member of the set `aeiou`, it uses the nth member of the set `áéíóú` for its replacement.

Is there a way to do this using the flavor of regex that C# provides?

**Edit:** Just to make it clear, I'm looking for a way of doing this *inside a regular expression*.  The program I'm working with already allows the user access to regular expressions while running the program, so if this can be done with a single regex, it'll save a lot of people a lot of time.  These users do *not* have access to the C# source code.

Comment: Why not use a `Dictionary<string, char>`? Then when you do `symbols["a'"]`, it'll give you `á`

Comment: Because this is for a program that allows the user to write regexes for their particular task.  If it can be done with a regex, the user doesn't need access to the code.

Comment: i would also like to know the answer to this

Comment: What's wrong with a short-hand file? Then everyone can have different short-hands.

Comment: This program already allows the user a shorthand file, which allows the user to write regexes that they want the program to use on their data.  Writing a separate entry in the shorthand file for each replacement gets very tedious when you have a hundred entries in the same format.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2):

Here's a naive method:

```
string[] old = new string[]{ "a'", "e'", "i'", "o'", "u'" };
string[] new = new string[]{ "á","é","í","ó","ú" };

for (int i=0; i++; i<5)
{
     input = Regex.Replace(input, old[index], new[index]);
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question -- I'm looking for a way to do this inside a regex, not outside it.

Comment: I see, check out this ref then for conditional regex: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx#alternation_constructs

Comment: And sorry about the misunderstanding :)

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK regexes can certainly identify all of those contructs, but not perform transformations such as the replace that you want. However .NET does have an extension that allows programmatic replacements using a MatchEvaluator, as below:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.matchevaluator.aspx

So your regex could be as you said ([aeiou]') and you could use a dictionary to map the old values to the new values in the MatchEvaluator.